# Utils.sendHttpPostMultipart with Special characters

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I`m trying to do a Utils.sendHttpPostMultipart request but the value is wrong when I have special chars like **ã**, **é** etc

how to solve this?

here is my code:

```
List< NameValuePair > values = new ArrayList< NameValuePair > ( );
values.add( new RegValuePair( "Key", "Não funciona");
StringBuilder ret = Utils.sendHttpPostMultipart( "http://localhost/am.aspx", values );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");